# Show loading gif image while running client-side code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Assume the `loading` CSS class is attached to a div which contains an animated gif image ([the classic spinner](http://spiffygif.com/)).

```
$( document ).ready(function(){

  $(".button").click(function(event){
    $(".loading").show();
    // time-consuming code running in the browser
    $(".loading").hide();    
    return false;
  });

});
```

We have been accustomed to see the spinner image spinning while the client does an ajax request to the server, leaving control to the JavaScript engine which can animate the spinner until the ajax request's callback returns.

However, in the example above, there is no ajax involved and the "time-consuming code" is located *on the client-side*, meaning the JavaScript engine cannot animate the gif while doing some costly job on the client.

I am aware that there are no (native) threads in JavaScript, so how can I have that spinner shown and spinning while executing some JavaScript code?

Comment: Call your time consuming code in between show and hide...

Comment: What type of "time-consuming" code are you running? It is unusual to do large amounts on the client as it will effectively freeze the browser until that cycle completes.

Comment: @brso05 If I do that, the gif image will either not be shown, or if shown, it will appear frozen, i.e. not spinning.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It could be for example some computing logic before showing results to the user in a div on the page.

Comment: Animated gifs don't use JavaScript. The problem is that your cpu is being loaded down, not that the image animation is blocked.

Comment: As @isherwood implies, you need to offload any *processor-intensive* tasks to the server, so the browser does not block. Access those services via Ajax calls as you have previously for other tasks.

Comment: @MartinCarel have you tried converting your gif to a data url (base64) to see if the effect is the same? see http://xaviesteve.com//pro/base64.php

Comment: @MartinCarel can you provide the entire example on jsbin or jsfiddle ? And is using plain text, ie "loading...", instead of a animated GIF an option ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the situation is just as you say it is, this would be a rare scenario where it would make sense to put Web Workers to use. Chances are, you'd want to implement them in a way that provides a fallback that either displays a frozen GIF, or tries to do partial work based on timeouts, allowing the JavaScript call stack to complete occasionally so that it can do UI updating.

Compatible with IE10 and up, and pretty much everything else:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

A random, incomplete example of timeout steps to give you an idea:

```
function doPartialWork() {

    //// do one "step" of the complex logic.

    // If complete, run a callback (and terminate without starting the timer)
    if (complete) {
        runCallback();
    }
    else {
        // Start another slice of work on the next processing cycle
        setTimeout(doPartialWork, 1);
    }
}
```

Googlers: If the above link is broken, search for resources on "Web workers".

Comment: This use of `setTimeout` to split the task into time-slices is actually a reasonable solution :)

Comment: You do need to stop the timer chaining if the task is complete though... put the `setTimeout` on an `else`.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie True. That's not even the half of what's missing from my example function though. It's really just there for the basic idea.

Comment: Yes, but wrong code is misleading... Have adjusted it and upvoted now as it is helpful. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Well, it's still *wrong* code, by that definition. You can't really call pseudocode "wrong" if it doesn't run. I didn't pass in a "runCallback" method, plus in JQuery it should probably return a promise instead. Plus you'd need a mechanism to maintain object state between steps of execution. The poster at least needs to be perceptive enough to recognize the many things that need to be added for this to work at all; so your edit was kind of just a drop in the bucket. Do you want to fill up that whole bucket?